# how to reduce a duplicate 2d array in to one

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have the following 2d array that I am looking to reduce the duplication into one based on the first value of the array.

```
['AA' 'Put' 1]
['AAL' 'Call' 20]
['AAL' 'Put' 8]
['AAP' 'Call' 1]
['AAPL' 'Call' 1]
['AAPL' 'Put' 2]
['ABBV' 'Call' 1]
['ABBV' 'Put' 1]
['ABNB' 'Call' 6]
['ABNB' 'Put' 2]
['ABT' 'Call' 1]
['ACB' 'Call' 8]
['ADBE' 'Call' 1]
['ADP' 'Call' 1]
['AEO' 'Put' 1]
['AEZS' 'Call' 1]
['AG' 'Call' 1]
['AGNC' 'Put' 1]
['AHT' 'Call' 1]
The output I am looking is like this:
      call put
['AA' '0' '1']
['AAL' '20' 8]
['AAP' '1' 0]
['AAPL' '1' 2]
['ABBV' '1' 1]
['ABNB' '6' 2]
['ABT' '1' '0']
['ACB' '8' '0']
['ADBE' '1' '0']
['ADP' '1''0' ]
['AEO' '0' '1']
['AEZS' '1' '0']
['AG' '1' '0']
['AGNC' '0' 1]
['AHT' '1' '0']

here is my attempt
    arr2 = [[],[]] #the data
    twoDarry = []

    for items in range(len(arr2)):
        print(arr2[items])
        if(items+1<len(arr2)):
            if(arr2[items][0]==arr2[items+1][0]): #check if duplicate
                tmparr = []
                tmparr = arr2[items]
                tmparr.extend(arr2[items+1])
                twoDarry.append(tmparr)
            else:  # not duplicate
                twoDarry.append(arr2[items])
```

If a call or put is mission(meaning there is no duplication), then put zero as a value. Converting this to panada is not an option as there have been compatibility issues that I had to deal with at some point. What am I missing?

Comment: do you expect "duplicate" entries to repeat several times?

Comment: You should try to format your 2D list correctly first.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am going to assume your data array is properly formatted as a list of lists as shown below:

```
indat = [['AA', 'Put', 1], ['AAL', 'Call', 20], ['AAL', 'Put', 8], ['AAP', 'Call', 1], ['AAPL', 'Call', 1],
        ['AAPL,', 'Put', 2], ['ABBV', 'Call', 1], ['ABBV', 'Put', 1], ['ABNB', 'Call', 6],
        ['ABNB', 'Put', 2], ['ABT', 'Call', 1], ['ACB', 'Call', 8], ['ADBE', 'Call', 1],
        ['ADP', 'Call', 1], ['AEO', 'Put', 1], ['AEZS', 'Call', 1], ['AG', 'Call', 1], 
        ['AGNC', 'Put', 1], ['AHT' ,'Call', 1]]
```

Given what you have described in your question, I am further making the assumption you would like a function which takes the array as a variable and produces the desired output as a list of lists. Assuming these assumptions are correct, the following function will work.

```
def reduceArray(arr: list) -> list:
    indict= dict()
    for itm in arr:
        cv = indict.pop(itm[0], [0, 0])
        if itm[1] == 'Put':
            if cv[1] == 0:
                cv[1] = itm[2]
        else:
            if cv[0] == 0:
                cv[0] = itm[2]
        indict[itm[0]] = cv
    rslt = []
    for ky, val in indict.items():
        rslt.append([ky, val[0], val[1]])
    return rslt
```

executing:

```
reduceArray(indat)
```

Produces:

```
[['AA', 0, 1],
 ['AAL', 20, 8],
 ['AAP', 1, 0],
 ['AAPL', 1, 0],
 ['AAPL,', 0, 2],
 ['ABBV', 1, 1],
 ['ABNB', 6, 2],
 ['ABT', 1, 0],
 ['ACB', 8, 0],
 ['ADBE', 1, 0],
 ['ADP', 1, 0],
 ['AEO', 0, 1],
 ['AEZS', 1, 0],
 ['AG', 1, 0],
 ['AGNC', 0, 1],
 ['AHT', 1, 0]]
```